# Creating object with name in a variable

Tags: php, variables, namespaces

just a little problem:

```
namespace App\Model\Repositories\Components;

use App\Model\Repositories\Entities;

class Foo 
{
    private function foo() 
    {
       // 1) Does work
       new Entities\Article;

       // 2) Doesn't work
       $class = 'Entities\Article';
       new $class;
    }
}
```

Why the first case works and the second one doesn't? The error message is "Class 'Entities\Article' not found". PHP 7.1. Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: try $class = '\App\Model\Repositories\Entities\Article';

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I have read this page. And according to it, both ways should work (as far as I understand how it works).

Comment: @katona.abel Yes, this one works, thanks! But still - why the second way does not?

Comment: you imported the namespace 'App\Model\Repositories\Entities', but when using the string classname it does not use the imports so it cannot resolve it. so you have to provide the full path

Comment: @katona.abel Beautiful explanation, thank you!